# Difference between two types of shell arithmetic

Tags: bash, shell-script, arithmetic

What is the difference between the following two shell arithmetic commands:

```
echo $[ $var1 - 1 ]
echo $(( $var1 - 1 ))
```

Assuming var1 = 5 for example.

Comment: In neither case you need the sigil, just `echo $[ var1 - 1 ]` and `echo $(( var1 - 1 ))` is enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From man bash:

```
Arithmetic Expansion
   Arithmetic expansion allows the evaluation of an arithmetic 
   expression and the substitution of the result.  The format 
   for arithmetic expansion is:

          $((expression))

   The old format $[expression] is deprecated and will be 
   removed in upcoming versions of bash.
```

Comment: You beat me to the answer while I was looking for this manpage snippet.