# $[...] parameter expansion

Tags: bash, shell-script

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4892546/5411198) I learned that `:` can be used to get the side effects of a parameter expansion. I stumbled upon this code which uses a parameter expansion that looks new to me:

```
$ R=32; : $[R--]; echo $R
31
```

Here  `: $[R--]` seems to be equivalent to `((R--))`. What is `$[]`? And is it documented in `man  bash(1)`? I couldn't find it on the man pages.

Comment: Thanks that answers my question. Then this should be a duplicate

Comment: See also [What does a dollar sign followed by a square bracket mean in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209833/what-does-a-dollar-sign-followed-by-a-square-bracket-mean-in-bash)

Comment: @JeffSchaller, with that title, that question is rather misleading...

Comment: searching for questions with symbols is hard; fortunately, steeldriver's comment text had enough for me to go on, and found that Q/A

Comment: @JeffSchaller, I know, the search sucks for them. I just hoped there would have been a better one to point to, and didn't see that other link when typing.

Comment: @ilkkachu if you do happen to find any more, please ping me here and I'd be happy to add them!

Comment: @JeffSchaller, well, I edited the duplicate list...

Comment: I tried to look through the old docs and thought I saw a mention that the `$[...]` would be removed in a future version, but now I can't find it. (@steeldriver, did you quote that from somewhere in a comment?) It still seems to work in Bash 5.0, so apparently we're not far enough in the future yet. :)

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66977/difference-between-two-types-of-shell-arithmetic

Comment: @ikkachu I found it in `man bash` (version 4.4.20(1)-release) under `Arithmetic Expansion`

Comment: @steeldriver, ah right. It wasn't in the older versions. Thanks.